# Dependency on non-maven module

Tags: maven, dependencies

The entire java project has an ant build; however couple of module(s) have maven build too.
My new module (maven built, say A) has dependency over an existing module(or simply a folder?, say B) which is being built using ant which just packages the src into jar and drops it inside the project.
Maven build for module A fails (unable to locate moduleB files); Options - 
1. Package module B using maven, push to m2_repo

I do not want to go with this option.
Please let me know what are the other options available for the same.

Comment: Would it be possible to convert your build into a multi-module build?

Comment: Before we go into the details of another solution, can you tell me the reason for not doing ` Package module B using maven, push to m2_repo` ?

Comment: @SaifAsif , Ralf - packaging module B using maven is not an option because its dependent module again uses only ant. There is no uniform building mechanism (both ant + maven is used). Are you coming to tell - then build entire (multi) module using maven?

Comment: If there isn't any uniform building mechanism then already you will have to cross out a number of feasible solutions and go with some of the non-feasible ones.

Comment: You can create a Maven project that represents module B, without Mavenizing module B itself. Instead this project would assemble its output (say a JAR file) together with whatever nifty things you need on basis of the output of the Ant build. That output you can depend on from project A. It abstracts the crap away behind the fake module B.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the source of all your modules, and if you decided that Maven is your way to go forward, then I recommend to to go all-in as soon as possible. If you do not then you will have continuous problems for the two build strategies to play along. And not only during build time but also at deploy time when it is time to collect all your runtime dependencies. Unless you build one uber-JAR as your only deployable artifact.

If your modules will (almost) always release in sync, then consider using a multi-module project setup.

When I say "all-in" then I do not mean that you have to give up Ant completely. You can use the maven-antrun-plugin to kick of your existing ant builds.

You should also consider running your own repository server, e.g. [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), to take full advantage of your maven builds.